# how to highlight currently clicked h3 and li elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a accordian-style nav here. So every time an H3 is clicked, the list items drop down.

1.I want to color the H3 green if it's clicked, so users know what's currently clicked.
2.I also want to color whatever item/dog is clicked ( the < a > elements). 
So the currently clicked Heading and subheading should both be highlighted.

```
 <div id="accordian">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id=menu>
            <li class="active">
                <h3>ITEMS</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#item1"> item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#item2"> item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#item3"> item3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

             <li>
                 <h3>dogs</h3>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href='#dog1"> dog1</a></li>
                      <li><a href='#dog2"> dog2</a></li>
                      <li><a href='#dog3"> dog3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

THis is what I tried so far for 1, it doesn't work. Also, not sure how to do 2.

```
.sidebar-nav li.active{
color:green;

}
```

```
  $('ul.sidebar-nav li h3').on('click', function(){
            $('ul.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$('ul.sidebar-nav li h3').on('click', function(){
    $("ul.sidebar-nav li ul li, ul.sidebar-nav li h3").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('ul.sidebar-nav li ul li').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).parents("li").find("h3").hasClass("active")){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordian">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id=menu>
            <li>
                <h3>ITEMS</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#item1"> item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item2"> item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item3"> item3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

             <li>
                 <h3>dogs</h3>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#dog1"> dog1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#dog2"> dog2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#dog3"> dog3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The idea is to use the clicked element to find the `h3` and `li` that need to be highlighted. Also, in CSS, make the selector more generic so it will apply to both the `h3` and `li` elements.

Comment: I need to color the H3 elements first, and then the li ones under that, will it work for that?

Comment: @Angular This will highlight the clicked `li` and the `h3` element that is in the same parent.

Comment: @Angular you can click "Run code snipped" to see how it works.

Comment: I need it the other way around. The h3 should be clicked first, and then highlight the li clicked after.

Comment: Okay I tried this and it doesn't work because I have my h3 color set to blue initially .sidebar-nav li h3{ color:blue}. SO the green is overridden

Comment: @Angular You can fix that by adding a more specific rule in CSS, something like `sidebar-nav li h3.active{ color:green;}`, make sure to add it after the `sidebar-nav li h3{...}` rule.

Answer (score 0):

You are not targeting the H3 tag with your active class.  In your code, $(this) is referring the the li.  You will need to target the parent H3 of clicked li that has the listener.

EDIT

In the code example see my comments to the lines I added.  I target all h3 tags and remove the active class to clear everything out, then I target just the parent h3 tag of the clicked li.

Also update your style to have a less specific class for any element with class active:

```
.active {
       color:green;
    }

$('ul.sidebar-nav li').on('click', function(){
      $('ul.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('active');

      // removes all active classes on h3 tags  
      $('#accordian').find('h3').removeClass('active');   

      $(this).addClass('active');

      // add active to parent h3 as well
      $(this).parents('h3').addClass('active');
});

// If you want them to to highlight independently you need 2 listeners

$('#accordion').find('.sidebar-nav h3').on('click', function() {
    // removes all active classes on h3 tags  
    $('#accordian').find('h3').removeClass('active'); 
    // add active to parent h3 as well
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});

$('#accordion').find('.sidebar-nav a').on('click', function() { 
    $('#accordion').find('.sidebar-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Update your css to just have color green be on the `.active` class.  Your active class is currently only applying to a specific `li`